# Transfer 27 to AA or 28 to AB in Google Apps Scrips

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use Google Apps Scrips to output a formula, but in the formula, the column name is character(AA,AB,AC...). 
So I tried to find a function to transfer the number to character, but failed, because all the code I found is not Google Apps Scrips, I'm only a new user on Google Apps.
Wish somebody can help me, Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get the column name depending the number.

```
function Demo(){
  var col = "10";
  Logger.log(nameCol(col))
}

function nameCol(value){
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(1,value);
  return cell.getA1Notation().replace("1","");
}
```

By this way in this thread the 2 answers to get number of column or name of column.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It can work. I use a very foolish method to finish it too. I use a number divide by 26 and get the quotient and remainder. Then transfer to character. But yours is the best! Thank you again.

Comment: It was a good question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A proposal, don't know how you extract information from the function but if you have the col name the code below will return the num col.

```
function Demo(){
  var col = "AC";
  Logger.log(numCol(col))
}

function numCol(value){
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(value+"1");//We assume script is launched from a spreadsheet, to be adapted if not the case.
  return cell.getColumn();
}
```

Stéphane

Comment: Thanks, your code is useful too. But I need transfer a number to a character...

Comment: Sorry miss understanding on my side.

Comment: You are welcome, and do you have some suggestion for this question? I have tried to do it. But I did't know how to transfer a number to a character, it's not a Java script, (char)number can't work....